# How to specify that two type variables are the same?

Tags: haskell, types, type-signature

Say code like this:

```
fun :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
fun f as = someLogic as
  where someLogic :: [a] -> [b]
        someLogic xs = map f xs
```

The last line would be complained by compiler that type `a` for "`f`" is not the same as type `a` for "`someLogic`".

So what could I do to let the compiler know that both types `a` are the same thing?

Comment: `ScopedTypeVariables` is the thing to Google. I'll come back and add a proper answer when I'm not on a phone, if someone else hasn't by then.

Comment: or, you could just omit the type signature `someLogic :: [a] -> [b]`, if you don't really need it. and in that simple code, you don't need it.

Comment: @WillNess, Yes, that is one way to go. But I have all warnings on, so it would annoy me.